# Dynamic value in multiple React Native Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-modal

I have 6 dropdowns in a vehicle compare screen. Dropdowns are created with React Modal. All the data in the dropdowns are dynamic.

[image: dropdowns]

When the page is loaded data to be shown in the first two modals, car brands, are fetched and they are shown in modals are dropdown.

When a car brand is selected another api call is made to get the models available in that brand. This data is populated on the second dropdown.

Since there is two dropdowns for selecting model for two different brands, when one brand is selected both the model dropdowns get updated.

How can I change my code such that i can make this work and make it scalable in future if i have to add more number of cars fo comparing?

**Compare.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    SafeAreaView,
    ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';


import PickerModal from '../components/PickerModal';
import * as Api from "../api/app";


export default class CompareVehicles extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            vehicleCompany: [],
            vehicleModel: [],
            vehicleSubModel: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: true,
        });
        this.getVehicleBrand();
    }

    getVehicleBrand = () => {
        Api.getVehicleBrands()
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                if (responseJson.success === true){
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        vehicleCompany : responseJson.data
                    });
                }  else {
                    alert("Error Loading Content")
                }
            });
    };

    submitBrand = async (data) => {
        Api.getVehicleModel(data)
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                if (responseJson.success === true){
                    this.setState({
                        vehicleModel: responseJson.data
                    });
                }  else {
                    alert("Error Adding Content")
                }
            });
    };

    submitModel = (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    };

    submitVariant = (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    };

    _renderPickerModal = (index) => {
        if (this.state.vehicleSubModel.length) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <PickerModal onSubmit={this.submitBrand} type={'light-dropdown'} data={this.state.vehicleCompany}/>
                    <PickerModal onSubmit={this.submitModel} type={'light-dropdown'} data={this.state.vehicleModel}/>
                    <PickerModal onSubmit={this.submitVariant} type={'light-dropdown'} data={this.state.vehicleSubModel}/>
                </View>
            )
        } else if(this.state.vehicleModel.length) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <PickerModal onSubmit={this.submitBrand} type={'light-dropdown'} data={this.state.vehicleCompany}/>
                    <PickerModal onSubmit={this.submitModel} type={'light-dropdown'} data={this.state.vehicleModel}/>
                </View>
            )
        } else if (this.state.vehicleCompany.length) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <PickerModal onSubmit={this.submitBrand} type={'light-dropdown'} data={this.state.vehicleCompany}/>
                </View>
            )
        }
    };

    render() {
        if(this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <SafeAreaView style={[styles.safeArea, styles.alignJustifyCenter]}>
                    <ActivityIndicator/>
                </SafeAreaView>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
                    <ScrollView
                        style={styles.scrollView}
                        scrollEventThrottle={200}
                        directionalLockEnabled={true}>
                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                                {this._renderPickerModal}
                            </View>
                            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                                {this._renderPickerModal}
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                </SafeAreaView>
            );
        }
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    safeArea: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    alignJustifyCenter: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    scrollView: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        paddingVertical: 15,
        paddingHorizontal: 20
    }
});
```

**PickerModal.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Modal, TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default class PickerModal extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        index: PropTypes.number
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            pickerTitle: this.props.data[0].name,
            pickerValue: this.props.data[0].id,
            pickerDisplayed: false,
            index: this.props.index
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log(this.props)
    };


    submit = () => {
        const { pickerValue } = this.state;
        const { index } = this.state;
        if (pickerValue) {
            this.props.onSubmit(pickerValue, index);
        }
    };

    setPickerValue(content, index) {
        this.setState({
            pickerTitle: content.name,
            pickerValue: content.id,
            index: index
        }, () => this.submit());

        this.togglePicker();
    }

    togglePicker() {
        this.setState({
            pickerDisplayed: !this.state.pickerDisplayed
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    style={{width: '90%'}}
                    onPress={() => this.togglePicker()}
                    underlayColor='transparent'>
                    <View style={[styles.dropdown, this.props.type == 'dark-dropdown' ? styles.darkDropdown : styles.lightDropdown]}>
                        <Text style={[this.props.type == 'dark-dropdown' ? styles.darkDropdown : {}, {flex: 1}]}>{this.state.pickerTitle}</Text>
                        <Ionicons name={'md-arrow-dropdown'} size={25} style={[this.props.type == 'dark-dropdown' ? styles.colorWhite : {}, {marginLeft: 5, marginTop: 5}]}/>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <Modal visible={this.state.pickerDisplayed} animationType={"fade"} transparent={true}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        activeOpacity={1}
                        style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'}}
                        onPressOut={() => {this.togglePicker()}}>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            <View style={{padding: 20,
                                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                                bottom: 0,
                                left: 0,
                                right: 0,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                position: 'absolute', width: '100%' }}>
                                { this.props.data.map((value, index) => {
                                    return <TouchableHighlight key={index} onPress={() => this.setPickerValue(value, this.props.index)} style={{ paddingTop: 4, paddingBottom: 4 }}>
                                        <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}>{ value.name }</Text>
                                    </TouchableHighlight>
                                })}

                                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.togglePicker()} style={{ paddingTop: 50, paddingBottom: 20 }}>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#999', fontSize: 20}}>Cancel</Text>
                                </TouchableHighlight>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    colorWhite: {
        color: '#fff'
    },
    darkDropdown: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        borderRadius: 8,
        color: '#fff'
    },
    lightDropdown: {
        borderBottomWidth: 0.3,
        borderBottomColor: '#000'
    },
    dropdown: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
        paddingVertical: 0,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are doing is close enough. I'd create an intermediate ContainerComponent that should receive the brand and be completely isolated from the amount of cars that need to compare.

You just do something like:

```
render(){
     this.state.brandsToCompare.map(brand => <PickerModalContainer brand={brand}/>)
}
```

So the main Component will only be responsible for managing if the user picks 1, 2, or any amount of brands or cars they want to compare. The PickerModalContainer will have the logic for the fetching and depending on what the user selects, you just fetch and update the other PickerModals. This way you really don't care about the other Pickers, since they don't "know" each other.

If, at the end you need to get some information to compare, you can expose functions as props to the PickerModalContainer can talk to the proper PickerModal underneath and return whatever you need from that modal.

I think it is not that much of a change to be honest, just some refactoring.

Comment: Im new to react native. Can you help me a bit more with this? First the user will have to select Maruti Suzuki and Mini. Only those two will be show first. Then Swift and cooper will be shown. In my case when user selects Suzuki, both Swift and cooper gets updated. How will i code so that only the PickerModal underneath will change? How can i get the submit back to the parent component in this case.

Comment: If you can create an Expo snack with a working code I can try to refactor it.